# "The operations timed out" when using SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to create a small app using C# framework to send email. However, it does not work. The app always gives me "The operations timed out." I do not why.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
     MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("to@gmail.com");

     MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromAddress.Address, toAddress.Address);
     mail.Subject = "Testing";
     mail.Body = "contents.";

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
     client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
     client.Port = 587;
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.Timeout = 100;
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

     try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the SMTP info provided here appropriate?

Comment: Try to set a higher timeout limit. It is in milliseconds.

Comment: `SmtpClient` implements `IDisposable` and should be in a `using` block .

Comment: @ImreGreilich you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Google help page: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en

Comment: @AustinSalonen -- that, and MailMessage as well

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to set a higher timeout limit. It is in milliseconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

namespace GmailSendTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("myusername@gmail.com");
            MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress("myusername@gmail.com");

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(fromAddress.Address, toAddress.Address);
            mail.Subject = "Testing";
            mail.Body = "contents.";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 10000;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword"); 

            try
            {
                client.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still gives me "The operation timed out". Is it because I use c# framework instead of html?? I saw some comments said because of smpt server not connect. Would that be the correct reason??

Comment: Most probably yes, it won't connect to the SMTP server. Try using port 465. I found that this should be used for SSL connection.

Comment: I tried still not working. Do I need to encoding the username and password to base64??

Comment: I tried your code. Only changed the Timeout to 10000 (and of course the send e-mail, recipient, username and password). It worked perfectly. How did you use the username? Only the text before @ is needed ("from" in the case of "from@gmail.com").

Comment: Still not working even I changed the username. Do I need to do some setting in my email box?? or do I need to kill the firewall?(I tried actually..not good :()

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ? :)
Try debugging with telnet to see if it works.
To check if your code works use smtp4dev.

Comment: I wouldn't think you need to change any settings in Gmail. Try to open a command window, and type this: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`. It should clean the window and write a single line like this: `220 mx.google.com ESMTP...`. If you get an error message instead, then it seems that something blocks your connection to the gmail smtp server.

Comment: I do get the single line like you said. If you do not mind, could you attach your entire code at somewhere so that I could download and run it?? Thanks for your helping!!

Comment: After creating a Windows Forms Application, I only added two using rows: System.Net.Mail and System.Net. Then placed a button and inserted the code to the click event.

Comment: When I typed telnet smpt.gmail.com 587 this time, it gives me Connet failed. But sometimes it does not. How to fix this connecting error??

Comment: It's hard to tell. It depends on what kind of network are you connected to, and what kind of network softwares do you use. If you use a router, it can restrict you from using this port many ways. If you're in a major network (like work), AD rules can also prevent you from connecting to the smtp. You may try to connect from another machine or from the same but from another network. But this is only the first step.

Comment: Google help page suggested trying port 25 and SSL, and that finally worked for me.

Comment: I had the same problem.  I was using port 465 and when I switched to port 587 it worked.  My email client (Outlook) works fine on port 465.  Perhaps that was the problem.  I'm wondering if there was a conflict with both applications using the same port.  Port 25 did not work for me.  It did not time out, but said it could not connect.

Comment: @MarkAinsworth Thanks for you answer with 587, it worked for me :)

Comment: @MarkAinsworth same here, you are a saviour

Comment: @MarkAinsworth this was my problem exactly, thanks.